# Node.js Secure random between

Tags: node.js

I have a hex string and want to generate a secure random hex string (or buffer) between zero (or another hex string) and this hex string.

Node.js `crypto` can only generate secure random bytes. So if the hex-string's MSBs are 0 it would take a long time to generate such a number.

How would you program such a function?

Comment: Where is your code? *if the hex-string's MSBs are 0 it would take a long time to generate such a number*: why??

Comment: lets say the string is '10000000' (hex) the first number has to be 0 (not 1-f). So it has to generate 8 numbers in average, right?